# Как установить начальный размер экстента партиции при преобразовании? ORA-02203: INITIAL storage options not allowed

Tags: sql, oracle

Пытаюсь преобразовать обычную таблицу в партиционированную. Начиная с 12c, функция `alter table modify partition ...` доступна для такого преобразования таблиц.

Есть таблица, у которой размер `initial_extent` установлен на 544 МБ. Это слишком много. Фактический размер первого экстента составляет 8 МБ. Когда преобразовываю, в итоге получается 90 разделов с начальным размером 544 МБ. Это приводит к утроению размера таблицы. Многие партиции пусты на 90% и более.

Как установить начальный размер экстента партиции в разумное значение во время преобразования?

Пересоздание таблицы `alter table move` с новыми параметрами хранения не будет решением, поскольку размер некоторых из этих таблиц составляет более терабайта. Возможно, что-то упускаю, но я не могу найти способ изменить или указать начальный размер экстента.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY Partition by range (mydatecol)
    interval (NUMTOYMINTERVAL (1,'MONTH')) (
        partition p1308 values less than (to_date('01-SEP-2013','dd-mon-yyyy'))
    )
    storage (initial 1m)
UPDATE INDEXES ONLINE;
```

Без клаузы `storage` работает, а с ней даёт ошибку:

> ORA-02203: INITIAL storage options not allowed

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Initial extent size when converting to partitioned table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67642490) от участника [@jparker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3277850/jparker)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67642490

Answer (score 2):

Надо указать клаузу `storage` для каждой партиции, а не для всей таблицы:

```
create table t (val int) storage (initial 10m)
/    
insert into t 
    select level x from dual connect by level <= 5
/
alter table t modify 
    partition by range (val) interval (1) (
        partition p1 values less than (2) storage (initial 8k),
        partition p2 values less than (3) storage (initial 64k),
        partition p3 values less than (4) storage (initial 128k));

select partition_name, initial_extent 
from user_tab_partitions
where table_name='T';
  
PARTITION_NAME   INITIAL_EXTENT
---------------- --------------
P1                        16384
P2                        65536
P3                       131072
SYS_P10883             10485760
SYS_P10884             10485760
```

Обратите внимание, так как это нужно делать для всех партиций, то автоматически созданные партиции будут иметь тот же начальный размер, что и исходная таблица.

Изменить можно с помощью клаузы `modify default attributes`:

```
insert into t values (6);
    
alter table t modify default attributes storage (initial 16k);
    
insert into t values (7);

select partition_name, initial_extent 
from user_tab_partitions
where table_name='T';
    
PARTITION_NAME   INITIAL_EXTENT
---------------- --------------
P1                        16384
P2                        65536
P3                       131072
SYS_P10883             10485760
SYS_P10884             10485760
SYS_P10885             10485760
SYS_P10886                16384
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67720008) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>